# Where to add disableHostCheck when I don't have a webpack.config.js file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Firstly, I'm sorry if this is a ridiculously basic question but here goes:

I have built a create-react-app and as such although webpack and webpack-dev-server are within my node-modules folder there does not seem to be a webpack.config.js file for me to include the disableHostCheck statement so I am getting an "Invalid Host header" message. OR should I not have to change anything if create-react-app has been used. Just in case it helps my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "recipe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8081",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have proxied my API to 8081 and I am running React on 8080. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any solution?. I am also having the same issue

Answer (score -1):

You should first run "npm run eject" to make all the react scripts, configuration, etc visible. AFter that, you should be able to able to see your webpack.config file inside the "config" folder.